# Escape param for contains phrase

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

My mssql stored procedure does a phrase match which needs quotes around it, but how can I do this when I pass in the param? Eg:

Works:

```
(@searchQ = 'all' OR CONTAINS((GoogleJob.title, GoogleJob.nonhtmlDescription), '"dev ops"'))
```

Doesnt work

```
@searchQ nvarchar(100)

(@searchQ = 'all' OR CONTAINS((GoogleJob.title, GoogleJob.nonhtmlDescription), '"@searchQ"'))
```

I have to escape it some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with full text search and contains, but I think this will work.

```
@searchQ nvarchar(100)
declare @searchQ2 nvarchar(102) = '"' + @searchQ + '"'

(@searchQ = 'all' OR CONTAINS((GoogleJob.title, GoogleJob.nonhtmlDescription), @searchQ2))
```

Comment: Thanks, also realised I could just pass it in with the quotes too